# WIndows Phone 8 Simulator not showing up

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-8

I am new with windows 8 development, I am running microsoft visual studio windows phone express 2012 and ran into a problem where when I try to run the application it just shows the default device selected and not the simulators.

I read some msdn forms where they said to install the SDK 8.0 but windows phone express already comes with the SDK 8. I have tried chnagin the application debug properties but there too the only option that is visible to me is device and not simulator given below is the attached screen shot for the same.

[image]

Hence my query is how can I get my application working with the simulator for testing purpose, and where is the setting where I can see how many simulators are supported by default by the current version of the SDK ?

Comment: Which simulator do are you looking for - windows 8 or Windows phone 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS rightly specified by LZH, Emulator will require SLAT(Second level address Translation) and should support Hyper-V.

If the processor supports .Enable Hyper-V and Enable virtualization from BIOS for latest emulators.
Check this link below.
http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/support/configure-bios.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The requirement for the Emulator is

- Windows 8 Pro edition or greater
- Requires a processor that supports Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)

check if your processor support SLAT.
SLAT was introduced in the Nehalem microarchitecture found in certain Core i7, Core i5, and Core i3 processors.
Hence if your processor isn't iCore and above, chance are you won't be able to run the emulator because it requires Hyper-V

However you would still be able to test it on a real Windows Phone 8 device if you have one.

Comment: Use this tool to check whether the CPU is SLAT-compatible: https://slatstatuscheck.codeplex.com/