# Windows 8 Emulator not seen in list

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am learning windows programming. now when i run my demo application visual studio 2012 showing following error :

```
Deployment failed because no Windows Phone 8 phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.
```

Now can any one  tell me how to run app in emulator?, since when I try to run app I can see only one option which is device.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the Hyper-V established in your windows 8 OS or a windows phone connected via USB?   Hyper-V needs to be set for the emulators to work if none are showing.   Also if you have a windows phone connected you have to unlock the device via the windows phone registration.

Comment: +1 You may be right that OP's OS doesn't meet the requirements. I would add some links: [Troubleshooting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681694(v=vs.105).aspx), [similar question one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/3c451563-85d5-4322-b9c2-2204307ae9f4/windows-phone-8-emulator-not-showing-in-visual-studio-2013-why?forum=wpdevelop), [similar question two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528362/windows-phone-8-simulator-not-showing-up).

Comment: I was looking for the link where it ran down a scenario to make sure your machine had the adequate things installed.  It made reference to the CoreInfo.exe to check if things were installed.   That is what I did and used when starting to work with windows phone applications on a VirtualBox running windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Select Emulator WVGA 512 from from the list where the run is.
[image]

Comment: There is no WVGA 512 Emulator or any other option in dropdown